# Not getting any data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api';

export const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const { data: { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate} } = await axios.get(url);
    return {confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate};
} catch (error) {
}
}
export const fetchDailyData = async()=> {
try{
    const data = await axios.get('${url}/daily');
    console.log("DATA",data);
    const modifiedData = data.map((dailyData) => ({
        confirmed: dailyData.confirmed.total,
        deaths: dailyData.deaths.total,
        date: dailyData.reportDate,
    }));
    return modifiedData;
} catch(error){
    console.log("DATA NOT FOUND");
    var r = []
    return r
}
}
```

Here I'mt trying to get data from this API: https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily

But Whenever I'm trying to call fetchDailyData , I'm only getting "DATA NOT FOUND" on the console

Comment: Please write `console.log("DATA NOT FOUND", error)` and paste the result in your answer. The endpoint you are calling supports cross origin requests so your code should work. The error may be in the `data.map`

Comment: No the error is in fetching the data from the API endpoint  because the console log written below the axios.get is also not printing.

Comment: Data not found Error: Request failed with status code 404, this is the error I'm getting

Comment: Take a look at the answer, this is your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the `'` wrong syntax, the `data.map` will also throw an error: `map is not a function`, because you are trying to map the response and not the response.data.

**You should do something like that:**

```
const data = await axios.get('${url}/daily');
```

To:

```
const response = await axios.get(`${url}/daily`);
```

**And your map:**

```
const modifiedData = data.map((dailyData) => ({
```

To:

```
const modifiedData = response.data.map((dailyData) => ({
```

Answer (score 2):

You used `'` instead of ` (near below escape button) to use string templates:

```
const data = await axios.get(`${url}/daily`);
```